link to tensorflow object detection dependencies
Please advise a link to list of libraries on which TensorFlow Object Detection API depends. in order to install each and every dependencies before moving forward

I've successfully installed tensorflow , win10 terminal as follows:
conda create -n env363  python=3.6.3 anaconda  # my problem was python version>
conda activate env363
The tensorflow versions installed are:
Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensorflow                1.14.0               h39a9291_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-base           1.14.0           py36h9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0                     py_0
Any further enhancements is much appreciated
